# Static reference to images file in my Database

Tags: android, database, image

Let's say I want to create a database with static references to images included in my Android App. 
If I use the drawable folder, the ids are dynamic and I can't use a static reference to them.

Since I want to use one column of my Database as a resource for suggestion icons in my App, using drawables files is not simple...

If I want to do it, in which folder should I put my .png files? And in the database, which url should I save for each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's actually pretty simple to use in the normal drawable folders and write in the DB as string/text.

the `Resources` object have a few methods to help you deal with it:

[`getIdentifier(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) use this to get the integer ID of the drawable, for example:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

and [`getResourceEntryName(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int)) use this to get the String name of the drawable, for example:

```
context.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: I solved saving in my database, as text, the following:
android.resource://com.mydomain.appname/drawable/icon1